# Find and replace text (multichars) in .js files on Linux

Tags: linux, sed, search-and-replace

I have many .js files named the same (got.js) where i just need to find and replace some text on them. The text to find is: 
`\x72\x6Fx75\x6E`

And is to be replaced with: `\x72\x6F\x75\x6E` (just a \ in the middle)

I have tried SED with find, exactly this one:
`find '/home/' -name 'got.js' -exec sed -i -e 's%\x72\x6Fx75\x6E%\x72\x6F\x75\x6E%g' '{}' %;` but i get an error `find: missing argument to '-exec'`. If i change `%`  to `\`, it don't show any error, files last modified date changes, but nothing changes on the files. 
Also, i should mention that this `\x72\x6Fx75\x6E` text is part of a big encoded phrase. I thought that this may be the problem, and putted the whole phrase in the sed, but the result was the same: nothing changes :-(

Hope that someone can help me on this.
 Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`find '/home/' -name 'got.js' -exec sed -i -e 's/\\x72\\x6Fx75\\x6E/\\x72\\x6F\\x75\\x6E/g' {} \;`

Edit: was a typo error on the original command line. 2 single quotes after ../g

Comment: Thank you very much @drookie. It did the trick. As i'm seeing, my problem was the escaping and delimitation :-( At your example, every  \ should be escaped with another  \ . Will try it in another complex way and let you know if anything goes wrong.<br />
Thanks again!